# earthquake usgs api filter by country

Tags: api, city, json, usgs

I am trying to get recent earthquake data using https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/ api.

For example this url (https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2020-01-01&endtime=2020-01-10&limit=50) returns, earthquake happened during 01st Jan 2020 to 10th Jan 2020. It returns earthquake happened all over the world. But, I want to filter this api for particular country like Japan, India..

Is there any way to filter earthquake usgs api data by country name?